# Power Query - Find and replace in one step instead of several

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a simple column here.

---

[image]

I am using Power Query to replace some values,

1 becomes 119, 2 becomes 201, 3 becomes 321

There are no particular logic to it, it's to correct the mistyped numbers by users.

---

I did a find a replace function.
`Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",1,119,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Name"})` which worked great.

I want to combine the other find and replace functions into one single step for cleaner code.

I tried this but didn't work.

`Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",{1,2},{119,201},Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Name"})`

**I don't want to have 10 different find and replace steps in my PQ just want to have one step.**

Answer (score 2):

## OPTION-1

Here below is the **M** code for all replace together-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlSK1YlWMgKTxkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    

    #"AllReplace" = [
        #"1" = "119", 
        #"2" = "201", 
        #"3" = "321"
    ],
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Column1",each Record.FieldOrDefault(AllReplace,_,_)}})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

**Note:** Need to number column as **Text**. You can convert the column to **Number** after the **Replace** Step.

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

## OPTION-2:

You can also create a custom column using the below code-

```
if [Column1] = 1 then 119 else if [Column1] = 2 then 201 else 321
```

**After** creating the custom column, you can keep or remove the source coulmn.